# Windows 10: Disappearing cursor on wake

Tags: windows-10

When my computer wakes up from low power mode,

the cursor disappears.

When I turn it off, a cursor appears.

**I am using additional acceleration applications.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I think you should clean the system cache.**

*You can use a suitable cleaning program for this.*

Answer (score 6):

On other computer I first restart PC and then unplug mouse and then plug it back.

It works too.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with kind of mouse pointer on the external monitors. After dockstation turn off and on - problem was dissaper.